# Добавить поддержку кириллицы в iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

вот мой код

```cs
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
public static void WriteToPDF(string filePath, string fileResult, string text)
        {

       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            reader.SelectPages("1-3");

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(fileResult, FileMode.Create));
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfContentByte pbover = stamper.GetOverContent(i);



                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pbover, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Мой текст #1:" + text), 400, 5, 0);
            }
 stamper.Close();

}
```

в PDF записывается только "#1"
как можно изменить код, что бы записался "Мой текст #1:"

Comment: не вижу указания каким шрифтом выполнять надпись. Не все шрифты имеют глифы для кирилицы. Попробуйте указать шрифт явно.

Comment: даже если добавить конкретный шрифт, все равно не запишет, к примеру Times New Roman имеет поддержку, ничего не изменилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно изменить код следующим образом

```cs
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
public static void WriteToPDF(string filePath, string fileResult, string text)
        {
 string ttf = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIAL.TTF");
            var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(ttf, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            var font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(baseFont, iTextSharp.text.Font.DEFAULTSIZE, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL);
       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
            reader.SelectPages("1-3");

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(fileResult, FileMode.Create));
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfContentByte pbover = stamper.GetOverContent(i);



                ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(pbover, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Мой текст #1:" + text,font), 400, 5, 0);
            }
 stamper.Close();

}
```